# Handling paginated reports with huge number of parameters

Tags: post, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am trying to build a Paginated report with many number of parameters [8] and with huge number values [100-1000] for each parameter. Because of the complexity in the UI, I intend to develop two reports.

1. Report [.pbix] where the user can select the parameters and values
2. The paginated report [.rdl] that's the actual result with pages of data.

The Report 1 will be calling the report 2, based on a generated URL. THis works for a limited number of parameters  but since the list is huge, the reports are not generated because of the limitation on the URL length on the browser[chrome&IE]. I am looking for a solution that can work with an indefinite number of parameters. Trying to make this work with FORM and POST method so the parameters can be sent within the header itself.

Have looked into the https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Paginated-Report-Using-URL-Parameters-and-Select-ALL/td-p/8... but the solution doesnt always work as the URL length is huge.

Is there a solution that can work with any number of parameters. preferably something that uses FORM/POST method. Open to any other suggestions - please let me know.

Regards,

Sasi.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am sorry to inform you that according to Microsoft there are some strong limitations with transferring selected parameters when directing the user into Report Builder.

1. you can define no more than 10 filters conditions.
2. URL bytes length is very limited

For example, even if you use only one slicer, if the user selects 24 different values in that slicer it will break the URL toward Report Builder.

What is the exact Business Need? Either the business accept some strong limitations or you need to think of another implementation.
An example of possible limitation to propose the business is: Power BI passes only Year and Month to Report Builder, next, the user in Report Builder need to re-select the additional parameters.

Comment: Thanks Seymour. But unfortunately, this is kind of mandatory for our design as we have some key paginated reports with a big list of slicers. In order to have a better UI [read it as - appease the business] we had to separate the Slicers and the actual paginated report as different pages. So the users will initially access the Slicers page and once they press View Report they will end up in actual paginated report which is sliced based on the values selected [and communicated as URL parameters or 'POST ??'] in the Slicer page. URL params is limiting in terms of values selected hence the issue.

Comment: I know very well your problem. U fortunately this type of solution cannot be implemented because of Microsoft limitations. Hence, my suggestion to identify a different approach or try to solve the business need in a different way.

Comment: I know very well your situation and unfortunately it is not a possible solution because of Microsoft limitations. Hence, my suggestion to change implementation or go back to business needs and try to solve the problem in a different way. I am sorry.